# Process hangs and PIPE is blocked

Tags: c++, perl, ipc, darwin

I seem to have a deadlock. I have perl scripts forking and calling another perl scripts. And the process hangs somewhere.

I am running the program on :
Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan 6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

"lsof" has 4 entries referring to the same PIPE:

perl5.12  1414            root    1      PIPE 0x48937dc1254fe937      16384        ->0x48937dc1254fe727

perl5.12  1768            root    1      PIPE 0x48937dc1254fe937      16384        ->0x48937dc1254fe727

perl5.12  1759            root    1      PIPE 0x48937dc1254fe937      16384        ->0x48937dc1254fe727

perl5.12  1760            root    1      PIPE 0x48937dc1254fe937      16384        ->0x48937dc1254fe727

I am suspecting that is the cause of the hang.
Do we have any commands that could tell me which process reading/writing into this PIPE?
Or any further information would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question, but off topic here.  Try serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 0):

There's two likely possibilities I can think of:

1. There's deadlock due to output buffering. Try enabling autoflush on all the output pipes. This is likely if two processes are communicating bidirectionally using pipes: they each write something and wait to read a response, but because the output is buffered the response is never sent to the pipe.
2. A process is waiting for EOF on the pipe, but it never comes. If the pipe is created in a parent process and then inherited by a child process, you need to ensure that all the processes close the write end of the pipe so that the reader will read EOF.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I tried to enable autoflush on all the  fds (fd->autoflush;) for scripts that are hanging (ps -ax). But it dint help. I also made sure all the opens are closed. Is there any way of knowing which script is possibly reading or writing to the PIPE? ThankU.

Comment: Can I possibly close all the open file handles of a particular process? I do not have proc file system (/proc/<pid>/fd).

Comment: Maybe you can use `dtruss` to see what each process is doing. But I think you'll just find that they're all in `read()`, I don't know how much that will help.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar also explained the Child Processes can get stuck when the Output Buffer fills up. In this case you will find the Child Process stuck in the `write()` Function Call.

You will have to use Perl `IO::Select` Module in the Parent Process to continuesly read the Output Buffer from the Child and thereby empty it if the Output from the Child Process is bigger than the Buffer.

The official Perl Documentation at 
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html
explains:

> **sysread FILEHANDLE,SCALAR,LENGTH**
>  Attempts to read LENGTH bytes of data
>   into variable SCALAR from the specified FILEHANDLE, using read(2). It
>   bypasses buffered IO, so mixing this with other kinds of reads, print,
>   write, seek, tell, or eof can cause confusion because the perlio or
>   stdio layers usually buffer data.

Further to see the System Activity I usually use the `strace` Command which nicely shows how each process reads and writes data.